# how to expand a div to use all the possible area

Tags: css, height, width

How can I tell a div to use the entire area marked with the red arrows no matter the size of the browser and no matter the div contents?

[image]

I tried: `<div style='height:100%;width:'100%'>...</div>` but it only takes the horizontal area, not the vertical. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The syntax should be `<div style="height:100%; width:100;">...</div>`. (Colon, not = sign)

Comment: @Laura it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o7u9hxou/

```
html
<body>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="topbar"></div>
  <div id="else"></div>
</div>
</body>

css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#else {
  background-color: green;
  height: 90vh;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 10%;
}
#topbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10vh;
  min-height: 20px;
}
#wrapper { 
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}
```